# Error during Show processing

Tags: plotting

In launching a program of thousands of lines of code that I have been writing for a few months, during the calculation phase we see temporary errors that capturing the screen are as follows:

[image]

then the zeros decrease, up to the last error phase:

[image]

although in the first lines I tried to hide them.

It must be said that once the calculations are completed, no error is obtained and everything is as desired:

[image]

Unfortunately I can not reproduce a minimum code to show this anomaly because I believe it is linked to the complexity of the code. I wanted to ask if anyone knows any strategy to make sure that no errors are displayed during the calculation phase, but that the desired result is shown only at the end.

I tried with "Quiet" but it does not work in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `{0}`, e.g.

```
Show[{{ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]]]},
  {ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]]/2]}, {0}}]
```

[image]

To supress the error messages and output use `Quiet` and `Check`, e.g.

```
Quiet@Check[Show[{{ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]]]},
    {ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]]/2]}, {0}}], ""]
```

Instead of `""` you could use a suitably sized blank graphic.

You may not need `Quiet` if you have switched off messages with `Off`.

Comment: @Tem Yes, you can wrap the `Show` object in `Check` as above.